# How to print to printer in c# using Media Type

Tags: c#, printing, .net-4.8

I want to be able to print to my Ricoh copier and select the tray by paper type ie Plain Paper, Special Paper, etc.  How can I query the printer for the available paper types (not sizes or trays) and then be able to print back using the paper type and not the tray.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is how I am setting the paper trays:

```
public static PrintDocument SetPaperSource(PrintDocument printDoc, string printer, string destinationTray)
    {
        var printDocSettings = printDoc;
        if (printDocSettings != null)
        {
            // Get the available paper sources (trays)
            PaperSourceCollection paperSources = printDoc.PrinterSettings.PaperSources;

            // Select the paper source (tray) you want to use
            PaperSource selectedSource = null;
            foreach (PaperSource source in paperSources)
            {
                if (source.SourceName.Equals(destinationTray, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    selectedSource = source;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Set the paper source (tray) for the print document
            printDoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSource = selectedSource;
        }
        return printDocSettings;
    }
```

Comment: I have the exact same task to solve. Did you ever figure out how to do it or found a different solution?